# Dynamics of a Centrifuge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force

If $10\mathrm{\ Nm}$ of torque are applied to a centrifuge with ballast and payload and we assume that the weight of the centrifuge itself is negligible (ignored), then $5\mathrm{\ Nm}$ go to the payload and $5\mathrm{\ Nm}$ go to the ballast for the duration of acceleration or time t-rev. While at speed the payload is released from the centrifuge and travels linearly away from the centrifuge. In order to slow the centrifuge ballast without payload to zero velocity only $5\mathrm{\ Nm}$ of torque must now be applied to the centrifuge for time t-rev. Where is the other half of the initially applied $10\mathrm{\ Nm}$ times t-rev gone?

Comment: Note the centrifuge will have a larger angular velocity after payload release, so t to speed up and speed down are different here.

Comment: @Triatticus I don't understand why/how the centrifuge will have a larger angular velocity after payload release. Are you saying that releasing the payload causes the centrifuge to accelerate?

Comment: Conservation of angular momentum

Comment: @Triatticus Could you please explain how conservation of angular momentum causes the centrifuge to accelerate?

Comment: Yeah I mistook that the payload will cary away the momentum, but another point of mine will partially still stand, the needed torque to decelerate the centrifuge in the same time is still different due to the reduction of the moment of inertia of the centrifuge. Remember that $\tau = I\alpha$ and so if you want to have the same time necessarily you have to alter $\tau$ to accommodate this.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the other half of the initially applied 10Nm times t-rev gone?

It is still in the payload. The payload still has its original angular momentum by $$\vec L=\vec r \times \vec p$$

Just because it is released and travels in a straight line at constant velocity (from the moment of release on) does not mean that the angular momentum disappears

**EDIT**: as requested in comments I am adding an explicit calculation of the angular momentum using the formula above.

Suppose that the payload of mass $M$ is released from the centrifuge of radius $R$ at time $t=0$. Thus for $t<0$ the position of the payload is given by $$\vec r = \left( R  \cos\left( \frac{v}{R}t \right),\ R \sin\left( \frac{v}{R}t \right),\ 0\right)$$ therefore the momentum of the payload is $$\vec p = M \ \vec v = M \ \dot {\vec r} = \left(- M v  \sin\left( \frac{v}{R}t \right),\ M v \cos\left( \frac{v}{R}t \right),\ 0\right) $$ which gives an angular momentum of $$\vec L = \vec r \times \vec p = \left(0,\ 0,\ MRv \cos^2 \left( \frac{v}{R}t \right) + MRv \sin^2 \left( \frac{v}{R}t \right) \right) = \left(0,\ 0,\ MRv  \right) $$

Now, after the release, for $t>0$ the position of the payload is given by $$\vec r = \left( R,\ vt, \ 0 \right)$$ therefore the momentum of the payload is $$\vec p = M \vec v = M \dot {\vec r} = \left(0,\ Mv,\ 0\right) $$ which gives an angular momentum of $$\vec L = \vec r \times \vec p = \left( 0,\ 0,\ M R v \right)$$

So the angular momentum of the payload is the same before and after the release and is constant over time, as required by the conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: How can units of angular momentum be in a linearly travelling object?

Comment: @Dale Huh? What do the units have to do with it? Angular momentum is given by L=rxp. This doesn’t disappear

Comment: So how do I calculate the angular momentum of the payload while it is travelling in a strait line?

Comment: Angular momentum is computed around the center of the centrifuge rotor, of course; distance of the released payload seems dominant, but its path doesn't go through the center.

Comment: Students always seem to need to be reminded that L = r x p is a nonzero constant for a particle moving at constant momentum in a straight line that does not include the origin.

Comment: @Dale I have added a detailed calculation of the angular momentum of the payload both before and after release. Please see the edit to my answer